# What is the meaning of n in n-octane and similar compounds?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, terminology

Straight-chain octane ($\ce{CH3(CH2)6CH3}$) is also called *n*-octane. What does the *n* stand for, and where did the term originate?

For reference, see the [PubChem entry for octane](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/summary/summary.cgi?cid=356) (beside "Chemical Names:")

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In this case, *n* means "normal", i.e. straight chain. This is somewhat of a holdover from the olden days, but in the case of octane in particular, it makes sense to specify *n*-octane if that is what you have. For example, the "octane" used as a standard gasoline engine fuel against which gasolines are rated (by definition, 100 octane) is actually not *n*-octane, but rather 2,2,4-trimethylpentane - a branched isomer of octane - in contrast to the straight chain version.

[image: Isomers of octane]

Comment: Okay I found a source for this information (under "Etymology"): http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/n-octane

Comment: Amusingly, 2,2,4-trimethylpentane is colloquially called iso-octane, which totally flies in the face of the n/sec/tert/iso convention.

Comment: @Lighthart Iso-octane would mean an isomer of octane, which 2,2,4-trimethylpentane qualifies. So why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: Iso typically refers to a 1-methylethyl motif.

Comment: Please note that the completely correct, exhaustive, preferred (and only?) IUPAC name of ‘*n*-octane’ is **octane**. Current IUPAC Nomenclature of Organic Compounds does not even mention the ‘*n*-' prefix anywhere (if I did not miss something).